# how to create an index for a non-deterministic function

Tags: sql, indexing

I have a table with Date-Of-Birth column. I have defined a function, say FIND_AGE, which takes it as input and returns age (it uses system date in calculations).

I want to optimize a query which returns all records having a certain age, say 30. I understand that we can't use non-deterministic functions (like FIND_AGE) while creating indexes.

Is there still a way I can create an index to optimize the query to fetch all records having age 30?

Comment: When you have an index on date_of_birth, you can do: `SELECT .... WHERE date_of_birth BETWEEN  adddate(now(),interval -31 year) and  adddate(now(),interval -30 year)`   (Note: you might find the specific version of `adddate` for your DBMS)

Answer (score 0):

I would advice if you have a performance issue to share the whole query. Generally, storing a date and having a index on it is enough to find particular records based on it.

For example, getting users born before 30 years on current date:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE dob = DATEADD(year, -30, GETDATE())
```

If you have billions of records, which is unusual for users data, I can accept this is the cause of your performance issue.

If not, it will be better to check how the data from this table is read. You currently can have a index on this column, which is ignore from the engine, because the index is not covering. For example, you are reading also the first and the last name of the users. So, you index can be:

```
CREATE INDEX INX_my_table_DOB_I_FisrtsName_LastName ON
(
   DOB
) 
INCLUDE (FirstName, LastName);
```

or you are filtering by country code, also, so the index will be:

```
CREATE INDEX INX_my_table_DOB_I_FisrtsName_LastName ON
(
   DOB
  ,CountryCode
) 
INCLUDE (FirstName, LastName);
```

If your users table has many columns or large columns holding text, xml, blob, etc. scanning the table and not using the index can be the root of your issues.

Comment: `INCLUDE`, when creating an index, is not supported by all DBMS's (like, for example, MySQL)

Answer (score 0):

If your table has an "updatedDate" column you could take the opportunity to maintain an indexed column "ageAtUpdatedDate" at the same time you update the "updatedDate" column at low cost: then the people having age X now are obviously among the ones having "ageAtUpdatedDate <= X" and you could reduce the data set size of people to test for "age = X", but he reduction of the data set size will depend on X in regard of the histogram of ages of your population, so the improvement will be "random"...

Answer (score 0):

It seems there exists an workaround (at least).

1. Define the DETERMINISTIC function with 2 parameters, where 2nd parameter have a default value = SYSDATE.
2. Define the index base on the function but do not provide 2nd parameter.

Example:
1.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fnc_example(pi_Date_of_Birth DATE, pi_SYSDATE DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE) RETURN DATE
DETERMINISTIC
IS
    val_return date;
BEGIN
    RETURN pi_Date_of_Birth + pi_SYSDATE;
END fnc_example;
```

2. 

```
CREATE INDEX index_name ON table_name(fnc_example(pi_Date_of_Birth));
```